# How to sort a HashMap's entries by comparing values, where each value is an int[]?

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary, java-8, comparator

I have a HashMap defined as `HashMap<String, int[]>`. The value is an `int[]` that will have exactly 2 numbers in it. What I want to do is sort this HashMap's entries by the sum of these 2 numbers.

Here is what I have. I am using Java 8. I just need to add the part where I sum the 2 `ints` in the `int[]` and treat it as one number then sort as I do below, but I am not sure how to add that part in.

```
hm.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
```

Comment: To do this you must write your own comparator.

Comment: I am new to comparators, but should I pass it a function that adds the two ints together in the int []?

Comment: `HashMap`s don't retain any order. If that's what you're trying to do, you'll need a different data structure. Or are you just trying to iterate over the entries in that order?

Comment: 'Sort a `HashMap` is already a contradiction in terms.

Comment: Edited to clarify sorting of map entries.

Comment: You can not sort `HashMap`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution with Java 8 Comparator lambdas:

```
map.entrySet().stream()
              .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(
                      (v1, v2) -> v2[0] + v2[1] - v1[0] - v1[1]));
```

Note that this solution has a risk of overflowing/underflowing, see [leeyuiwah answer](http://leeyuiwah%20answer) for a better solution to that. The idea is to use `comparingLong` method instead.

Comment: I am using PrintWriter to write to a file to check, but it prints the memory address, and I want to print the int[]?

Comment: This is unrelated but you could use Array.toString to print the array properly.

        `map.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue((v1, v2) -> v2[0] + v2[1] - v1[0] - v1[1]))
            .forEach(e -> {
                System.out.println("Key : " + e.getKey() + " Value : " + Arrays.toString(e.getValue()));
            })`

Comment: @Hesham -- Hi, I like this answer.  But I think there is a danger of implementing a comparator by a simple subtraction.  I provided my explanation as part of my answer below.

Comment: Agreed! Thanks for pointing this out, I will add a disclaimer.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that you can't create ordering element with HashMap.
My suggestion is to use 2 other Map:

```
Map<Integer,String> tempMap = new TreeMap<Integer,String>();
Map<String,int []> resultMap = new LinkedHashMap<String,int[]>();
```

First you need to copy your hm map into tempMap, the natural ordering in TreeMap will order your integer key in ascending order.

After you get the sorted result in tempMap, you can copy into resultMap to get the final result.

"Copy" means you iterate your old map then put the (key,value) in the new map.

This approach will cost you double memory, but it will run with the complexity O(n lg n).

If you want to use Comparator, you can use this approach:

```
hm.entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(
    new Comparator<int []>() {
    public int compare(int [] a,int [] b) {
        int sumA = a[0] + a[1];
        int sumB = b[0] + b[1];
        return sumA - sumB;
    }
}));
```

Comment: +1 for "you can't create ordering element with HashMap", but must admit I can't see any reason for not leaving it as TreeMap (no need for "resultMap")

Comment: The reason why I use resultMap is to preserve the original structure: HashMap<String, int[]>, String as key, int[] as value.

Answer (score 1):

This answer was actually inspired by the other answer by Hesham Attia and can be treated as an alternative solution to the question.

However, I also use this opportunity to discuss the potential problem of overflowing the `int` data type (see more below).

This solution uses the interface `Comparator.comparingLong()` with a `keyExtractor`, rather than the interface `Map.Entry.comparingByValue()` with a `comparator`.

(Both may suffer from data overflowing if we are not careful enough -- see Tests 2 and 3 below.)

```
hm.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparingLong(
                e -> ((long) e.getValue()[0])+e.getValue()[1]
           ))
```

Here is a full test program, which demonstrates the failed Tests 2 and 3 in the middle.  The correct answer of the sorting should be `e, b, c, a, d` (shown in the Test 4)

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class StreamSortedIntArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, int[]> hm = new HashMap<>();
        hm.put("a", new int[]{3, 1});
        hm.put("b", new int[]{1, 1});
        hm.put("c", new int[]{2, 1});
        hm.put("d", new int[]{Integer.MAX_VALUE, 1});
        hm.put("e", new int[]{Integer.MIN_VALUE, 1});

        // Test 1: 
        System.out.println("Test 1: hm before sorting: ");

        hm.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .forEach(StreamSortedIntArray::printEntry);

        // Test 2: 
        System.out.println("Test 2: hm after sort -- using Map.Entry.comparingByValue()"); 
        hm.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(
                        (v1, v2) -> v2[0] + v2[1] - v1[0] - v1[1]))
            .forEach(StreamSortedIntArray::printEntry);

        // Test 3: After sorting -- using Comparator.comparingLong()
        // WITHOUT protection against data overflowing the int type
        System.out.println("Test 3: hm after sorting: (using Comparator.comparingLong())"); 
        System.out.println("WITHOUT protection against data overflowing the int type"); 
        hm.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparingLong(
                        e -> e.getValue()[0]+e.getValue()[1]
                   ))
            .forEach(StreamSortedIntArray::printEntry);

        // Test 4: After sorting -- using Comparator.comparingLong()
        // WITH protection against data overflowing the int type
        System.out.println("Test 4: hm after sorting: (using Comparator.comparingLong())"); 
        System.out.println("WITH protection against data overflowing the int type"); 
        hm.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparingLong(
                        // protection against overflowing the int type
                        // cast to long before the sum operation
                        e -> ((long) e.getValue()[0])+e.getValue()[1]
                   ))
            .forEach(StreamSortedIntArray::printEntry);


    }

    public static void printEntry(Map.Entry<String, int[]> e) {
        String message
            = String.format("%s: %20s; sum=%d"
                            , e.getKey()
                            , Arrays.toString(e.getValue())
                            , ((long)(e.getValue()[0])+e.getValue()[1]));
        System.out.println(message);
    }

}
```

Output of this program -- Test 4 shows a correct answer, but Tests 2 and 3 do not:

```
Test 1: hm before sorting: 
a:               [3, 1]; sum=4
b:               [1, 1]; sum=2
c:               [2, 1]; sum=3
d:      [2147483647, 1]; sum=2147483648
e:     [-2147483648, 1]; sum=-2147483647
Test 2: hm after sort -- using Map.Entry.comparingByValue()
e:     [-2147483648, 1]; sum=-2147483647
d:      [2147483647, 1]; sum=2147483648
a:               [3, 1]; sum=4
c:               [2, 1]; sum=3
b:               [1, 1]; sum=2
Test 3: hm after sorting: (using Comparator.comparingLong())
WITHOUT protection against data overflowing the int type
d:      [2147483647, 1]; sum=2147483648
e:     [-2147483648, 1]; sum=-2147483647
b:               [1, 1]; sum=2
c:               [2, 1]; sum=3
a:               [3, 1]; sum=4
Test 4: hm after sorting: (using Comparator.comparingLong())
WITH protection against data overflowing the int type
e:     [-2147483648, 1]; sum=-2147483647
b:               [1, 1]; sum=2
c:               [2, 1]; sum=3
a:               [3, 1]; sum=4
d:      [2147483647, 1]; sum=2147483648
```

**The danger of implementing a comparator by a simple subtraction**

This problem is shown in the above test program (Test 2), but also has been
warned against in the Oracle/Sun Tutorial on Object Ordering

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html

> One last note: You might be tempted to replace the final return
>   statement in the Comparator with the simpler:
>
> return e1.number() - e2.number();
>
> Don't do it unless you're absolutely
>   sure no one will ever have a negative employee number! This trick does
>   not work in general because the signed integer type is not big enough
>   to represent the difference of two arbitrary signed integers. If i is
>   a large positive integer and j is a large negative integer, i - j will
>   overflow and will return a negative integer. The resulting comparator
>   violates one of the four technical restrictions we keep talking about
>   (transitivity) and produces horrible, subtle bugs. *This is not a
>   purely theoretical concern; people get burned by it.*

Answer (score 1):

More general solution, using proper comparator (which doesn't influenced of possible overflow problem), which will work for arrays of any length:

1) as you can not sort `HashMap` which doesn't preserve order of key, we need create new map - `LinkedHashMap`:

```
    Map<String, int[]> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

2) sorting it self:

```
    map.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(
                            (o1, o2) -> Integer.compare(Arrays.stream(o1).sum(), Arrays.stream(o2).sum()))
            )
    .forEach(se -> result.put(se.getKey(), se.getValue()));
```

**UPD:** Dear @Holger suggested usage of `Comparator.comparingInt(o -> Arrays.stream(o).sum())` which looks more compact, but does same job. For me personally my version looks more understandable, but Holger's one is more lambda-styler.

Comment: This could be simple misprinting. But do you agree , that it doesn't influence on result and is not general a mistake? Also, `a[0]+a[1]` is not the case, because if you read my answer carefully, I'm emphasised that my solution will work for arrays of any length.

Comment: Just fixed to `Integer.compare`

Comment: Well, `Comparator.comparingInt(o -> Arrays.stream(o).sum())` still does the same as your solution. If you want to write code to handle overflows, you would have to handle them when summing, as after `sum()` returns, widening the already truncated value to `long` doesn’t help. You could do `Comparator.comparingLong(o -> Arrays.stream(o).asLongStream().sum())` to handle overflows, but the question doesn’t make it clear whether this is actually intended.

Comment: Yes, I agree that `Comparator.comparingInt(o -> Arrays.stream(o).sum())` looks more nicer and more *stream-style*, thank you for you remark. If you wouldn't mind, I will leave my version, but add mentioning for you version as well

Comment: It’s your decision, however, since I have to scroll horizontally to see whether the second argument to `Integer.compare` is equivalent to the first (though it always should be), I don’t consider it more readable. But there’s a more important issue with your answer. The connection (or rather disconnection) between your two points isn’t clear. You need a `LinkedHashMap`, when you want to collect into a map of a specific order (which you don’t show). Your second point, on the other hand, shows, how to *process* the elements in a specific order, which doesn’t depend on the source map’s type.

Comment: TBH I'm confused about your last statement. Do you mean that it doesn't work as desired or it is not clear how does it work?

Comment: I just noticed that you are putting into the map within `forEach`. That’s not recommended. You can use `forEach` to *process* the elements (you should use `forEachOrdererd`, by the way), in which case you don’t need a `LinkedHashMap`. For *collecting* into a `LinkedHashMap`, you should use `collect` which the `groupingBy` or [`toMap` collector with a `Supplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-)…

Comment: I.e. `Map<String, int[]> result = map.entrySet().stream()  .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.comparingInt(o->Arrays.stream(o).sum())))  .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (a,b)->{throw new AssertionError("duplicate key");}, LinkedHashMap::new));`

Comment: I would be really appreciated if you could give me more information about **why** it is not recommended do this trick through `forEach`. Any performance issues?

Comment: Because TBH IMHO `.collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (a,b)->{throw new AssertionError("duplicate key");}, LinkedHashMap::new));` vs `.forEach(se -> result.put(se.getKey(), se.getValue()));` doesn't win the battle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135603/discussion-between-andremoniy-and-holger).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and IMHO best way is to not use a Map.Entry comparison method, because you aren't comparing by the key or the value but by a derived value:

```
map.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(e -> 0 - e.getValue()[0] - e.getValue[1]))
    .forEach(<whatever>);
```

The negative values create the reversed order your code suggests you want.